# django how to expire session after few seconds

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

I am using django session in my views for show message but the problem is I can't set session expire time. I tried this  `request.session.set_expiry(1)` but didn't work. here is my code:

```
 request.session["error_message"] = "your comment didn't submitted. Please try again"
 request.session.set_expiry(1)
```

I know I can also use **django messages** framework but here I need to be use session. The session message rendering in my template but only problem it's not expiring.

Comment: At first sight it looks like you are trying to mimic Django's messages framework. This framework guarantees that once rendered, the message is gone; so that might be better than working with session expiration: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/contrib/messages/

Comment: Willem Van Onsem I know about  django messages framework. But here I am trying to implement django session. My session message is rendering  in my template but only problem it's not expiring.